# Sorting a two-dimensional array of characters? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a 10X15 array of characters, where each row is a word.  My goal is to sort it in a descending order, from the largest value word at the top, at array[row 0][column 0 through 14] position, and the smallest value word at the bottom array[row 9][column 0 through 14]. Each row is a word (yeah, they don't look as words, but it's to test the sorting capability of the program).

**To clarify:**  What I need to do is this... considering that EACH row is a whole word, I need to sort the rows from the highest value word being at the top, and the lowest value word being at the bottom.

Edit:

Everything works now.  For anyone who has a similar question, look to the comments below, there are several fantastic solutions, I just went with the one where I create my own sort function to learn more about sorting.  And thanks to all of you for helping me! :)

Comment: Your description of the problem seems contradictory. It's not clear to me whether you want to sort the individual rows, the rows by the first letter, both, or all letters, mixing letters from different 'words'.

Comment: Convert each row into a string, add the string to a vector, once all the strings have been added, sort the vector, then write the strings back out to the array.

Comment: @us2012 I need to sort the words, each row is a word.  But there are words that are almost the same, up until like the last letter in them.  So obviously each letter (otherwise known as a column) has to be compared.

Comment: Are you writing your own sorting algorithm or can you use `std::sort`? And what do you mean by "highest value" and "lowest value"? Are you sorting in dictionary order?

Comment: It's better if I create my own.  But at the end of the day it'll come down to even getting this to work.

Comment: @David what happened to your post?

Comment: @Noobacode I removed it because I thought it didn't work for you. Do you want it back?

Comment: @David oh, I thought it was a website error.  Nah it's fine.  I'm working on the solution in my edit in my original post.  I got it to where I got every word into a vector (so it has 10 rows).  And I'm trying to compare and swap those rows, but it's not working so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using c++ so quit using arrays and begin with stl types:

Convert each row into a string:

```
string tempString
for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) {
    tempString.pushBack(array[foreachrow][i])
}
```

add them to a vector

```
std::vector<std::string> sorter;
sorter.push_back(tempString);
```

Do that for each row.

```
std::vector<std::string> sorter;
for each row {
    for each coloumn {
        the string thing

    }
    push back the string
}
```

Then sort the vector with `std::sort` and write the vector back into the array (if you have to but don't because arrays suck)

Comment: Yeah....... the problem requires me to use 10x15 array of characters.  So not like it's my choice.  Looking over your solution right now. :)

Comment: are you not allowed to import std::libs? because you can use stl containers then ouput as an array.

Comment: I'm allowed to do whatever I wish. But it has to be simple enough for a beginning C++ class.  The only requirements are that I have a 10x15 array of characters, in which each row is a word; I have to have a sorting function and a printing function.  That's it.  Also, it's telling me that string doesn't have .pushBack...

Comment: I am not having any luck converting it to a string.  It's says struct string doesn't have object pusBack, maybe it's push_back?  and what's foreachrow?  Is it this:    string tempString;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i) {
        tempString.push_back(array[i][COLS]);
    }

Comment: @Noobacode this is pretty clearly pseudo code. I am not going to write your homework for you. You will need to figure out the way to make the for loop do what you want. and yes, it is push_back().

Comment: No problem. I didn't know it was pseudo, so I was trying to figure out what those things meant.  I think I got it to work to the point where it stores the first letter.  But nothing afterwards... so I have to figure that out.  Edit: Just got it to store all the letters of each word.

Comment: Edit: Now I got it to where I store all 10 rows into a vector and I'm able to print it, so I know it's filled properly.

Comment: I got everything to work except the comparing part.  I have the code posted up in the original post.

Comment: @Noobacode you dont have to write your own sorting function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ std::sort will do it for you.

Comment: cool, that works. How would I reverse the order to descending? Since it sorts it in ascending order. Or should I just write them back into the array in reverse order after sorting?

Comment: I did this:     sort(sorter.begin(), sorter.end());
    reverse(sorter.begin(), sorter.end());

Comment: I also want to be able to write my own sorting function, especially since I'm so close to getting it to work in the code above.  If I'm not successful, then I'll just use this sort() deal since it works.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, you need `qsort`:

```
void qsort( const void *ptr, size_t count, size_t size,
            int (*comp)(const void *, const void *) );
```

That takes a void pointer to your starting address, the number of elements to sort, the size of each element, and a comparison function.

You would call it like this:

```
qsort( array, ROWS, COLS, compare_word );
```

Where you define compare_word to sort in reverse:

```
int compare_word( const void* a, const void* b )
{
    return strncmp( b, a, COLS );
}
```

Now, given that each word is 15 characters long, there may be padding to deal with.  I don't have absolute knowledge that the array will be packed as 10 by 15 instead of 10 by 16.  But if you suspect so, you could pass `(&array[1][0] - &array[0][0])` as the element size instead of `COLS`.

If you are not allowed to use `qsort` and instead must write your own sorting algorithm, do something simple like selection sort.  You can use `strncmp` to test the strings.  Look up the function (google makes it easy, or if you use Linux, `man 3 strncmp`).  To swap the characters, you could use a temporary `char` array of length `COLS` and then 3 calls to `memcpy` to swap the words.

Comment: I'm trying to use string.compare on my vector values right now using bubble sort, but it's not working out well (see original post).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your new code using `string` and `vector` is a simple typo:

`sorter[count] = array[count+1];` should be `sorter[count] = sorter[count+1];`

Comment: any ideas on why my vector to array conversion is not working in convArray()?

Comment: @Noobacode Same typo as the other one, only the other way round - `sorter[row][col]=tempString[col];` should be `array[row][col]=tempString[col];`.

Comment: Duh... oh my, I guess that's what all day in front of a computer does to you.  Thank you so much sir!